# Is it always safe to store store a derived class in base by value?

Tags: c++, polymorphism

The following code seem to run without problems.

```
struct base 
{
    virtual int foo() {return 0;}
};

struct derriveA : base 
{
    int foo() {return 1;}
} A;

struct derriveB : base 
{
    int foo() {return 2;}
} B;

int main()
{
    base a = A;
    base b = B;

    assert(a.foo() != 1);
    assert(b.foo() != 2);
}
```

But is it always safe to store a derived class by value? Is there any case where there is a risk for losing the derived data? Take for example the following code:

```
base* bb = new base(b);
assert(bb->foo() != 2);
```

Here i quite clearly tell the compiler only to allocate enough data for "base". However, (for me at-least) the assert is not triggered. Does this mean "bb" actually holds a pointer to deriveB? If so, would that mean that a memory leak occurs if it is deleted as a pointer to "base"?

*Compiler: Visual Studio 2012.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But is it always safe to store a derived class by value?

It depends on how you define "safe". In general, however, you do not want to assign an object of a derived class to an object of a base class, because that would cause *slicing* (as you probably realized). Polymorphism in C++ is realized through pointers or references.

> Does this mean "bb" actually holds a pointer to deriveB?

No. The assert fires if the condition is *false*. In your case, the condition is `true`, since `base::foo()` returns `0`, which is different from `2`.

Comment: Oh god! Shame on me. Sorry, i definitively meant to write == instead of !=.

Comment: @DavidJensen: In that case you would see that the assert is triggered ;)

Comment: I see, so in other words, it is NEVER safe! Because actually even the first one was triggered!

Comment: @DavidJensen: None of those two assertions (as they are in the current version of your question, at least) can fire. `base::foo()` returns `0`, and that is different both from `1` and from `2`

Comment: So in other words, it is impossible to store a derived class in a base variable by value!

Comment: @DavidJensen: Yes, *slicing* is what occurs. For polymorphism to work, you need pointers or references

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29065/discussion-between-david-jensen-and-andy-prowl)

Comment: @DavidJensen: I do not have time for discussing that now, sorry :(